# Drag and Drop images removed after dropping

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've started to build an drag and drop editor with html and Javascript. All in All it works fine.

You can drag images from a toolbar and drop them into the dropzone.

If you drop an image you actually create a copy of the original. thus you can drop them multiple times. The images get a left and top value to set their position. The value is relative (in %). Thats because it's possible to zoom in and out.

Now if I drop an image on another one it gets removed. Unfortunately I've got no idea how to prevent this.

I think The main issue is, that the dropped image becomes a child of the already dropped one and not of the dropzone. But preventing event capturing didn't helped.

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Here you see the main js drag and drop functions. I think thats the location where the problem can be solved. If you need any other code just let me know.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function DragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("application/json",        JSON.stringify([ev.target.id,(ev.offsetX || ev.clientX - $(ev.target).offset().left),(ev.offsetY || ev.clientY - $(ev.target).offset().top)]));
}

function DropIt(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData("application/json"));
    var width = document.getElementById("dropzone").clientWidth;
    var height = document.getElementById("dropzone").clientHeight;

    var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
    var original = document.getElementById(data[0]);
    copyimg.src = original.src;
    ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);

    copyimg.style.left =(ev.clientX - (screen.width - width) * 0.5 - data[1]) / width *100 + '%';
    copyimg.style.top = (ev.clientY - screen.height * 0.2 - data[2]) / height *100 + '%';
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to drop multi images into the dropzone but after you drop the second image the first image gets removed?

Comment: Not exactly. It’s already possible to drop multi images. But images get removed if I drop them on top of an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the target element, if the element is an IMG type get the dropzone parent element:

supposing the dropzone is a `<div>` element

```
   if(ev.target.tagName!="DIV")
      ev.target=$(ev.target).closest('div')[0];
```